input field value resets to initial state after it been cleared to empty value
So in my input field let's say an example, as I fetch details from backend and want to display in front end but also I need to edit the values
const [backendValue, setBEValue] = useState([]); // Fetched backend data
const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState({}); // Holds updated values

function handleChange(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setEditValue((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [name]: value // Update the specific field's value
  }));
}

return (
  <div>
    {backendValue.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {Object.keys(item).map((key) => (
          <input
            key={key}
            type="text"
            name={key} // Ensure the name attribute matches the key
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={editValue[key] !== undefined ? editValue[key] : item[key] || ''}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

So if the backend value has Hello and it display in input field and if I add extra character it works but my problem is
If I clear hello till e word and now it has h only as I deleted other 4 letter (ello) using backspace , And lastly if I clear the h too it resets to it's initial value as "hello" so I cant leave an empty field ??

Can you update the value to?
value={key in editValue ? editValue[key] : item[key] || ''}
The key changes are:

Changed the value prop condition from editValue[key] !== undefined to key in editValue. This checks if the key exists in editValue object, rather than checking if the value is undefined.
Using key in editValue ensures that even if the value is an empty string, it will still use the edited value rather than falling back to the backend value.


@JoshuaFolorunsho , Thank u sm it works

You're welcome.

@JoshuaFolorunsho -  Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

@JoshuaFolorunsho oh ok thanks, I use chatGpt for code readability but ok

The problem is that you are setting the value to the backend values if the edit value is empty and are setting the edit value when you change the input value meaning when you delet all the input text, edit value is false so the input is set to the backend values as was expected of it by the logic at value={editValue[key] !== undefined ? editValue[key] : item[key] || ''}.
You can modify the backend values so you only need to monitor one state as so:
const [backendValue, setBEValue] = useState([]); 

function loadValues(){
  const data = internet()
  setBEValue(data.data)
}

function handleChange(e) {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setBEValue((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [name] = value
  }));
}

return (
  <div>
    {backendValue.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {Object.keys(item).map((key) => (
          <input
            key={key}
            type="text"
            name={key} // Ensure the name attribute matches the key
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={item[key] || ''}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

